# How to use $.getJSON() properly?

Tags: jquery, json, httprequest, getjson

I'm having really strange problem with `$.getJSON()` on localhost. My test code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var url = "http://script.mydomain.com/location/newid"
        var url2 = "http://localhost/cms/location/newid"

          $.getJSON(url2, function(id) {
                alert(id);
          });
});
```

For url2 it works perfect but for url it's not working. Could anyone give some hint to solve this problem? These urls returns json (example: "34") if anyone would like to know.

**EDIT [SOLVED]:**

If anyone in future will use `$.getJSON` remember that you can't call "alien" domains.

When I executed overhead script under `script.mydomain.com` domain everything works fine!

Comment: You are likely running into the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 6):

AJAX request are limited by a cross-domain policy. Basically, you can't do ajax requests if they're not going to the server the original site was hosted on. It's slightly more complicated then that, but I would assume this to be the case.

Comment: OK, so how can I run this test script on cw.uppercut.pl and request location/newid ?

Answer (score 1):

You are limited by browser security to obtaining code from your own website (jquery uses XMLHttpRequest for getJSON). To get around it, you need to use jsonp (jquery adds a script tag) or create and append a script tag to your document.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you have a problem that you are trying to run in a browser ajax-request from the local host, to the domain cw.uppercut.pl.

This is not an issue of the library.

Comment: OK, so how can I run this test script on cw.uppercut.pl and request location/newid ?